# Bash: if [ "echo test" == "test"]; then echo "echo test outputs test on shell" fi; Possible?

Tags: bash

Is it possible with bash to execute a command from shell and if it returns a certain value (or an empty one) execute a command?

```
if [ "echo test" == "test"]; then
  echo "echo test outputs test on shell"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use backticks or `$()` syntax:

```
if [ $(echo test) = "test" ] ; then
  echo "Got it"
fi
```

You should replace `$(echo test)` with

```
"`echo test`"
```

or

```
"$(echo test)"
```

if the output of the command you run can be empty.

And the POSIX "stings are equal" `test` operator is `=`.

Comment: If you use bash's `[[ $(echo test) == "test" ]]`, no quoting is needed.

Answer (score 5):

something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPECTED="hello world"
OUTPUT=$(echo "hello world!!!!")
OK="$?"  # return value of prev command (echo 'hellow world!!!!')

if [ "$OK" -eq 0 ];then
    if [ "$OUTPUT" = "$EXPECTED" ];then
        echo "success!"
    else
        echo "output was: $OUTPUT, not $EXPECTED"
    fi
else
    echo "return value $OK (not ok)"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting the command betweeen $( and ) or backticks (`) will substitute that expression into the return value of the command. So basically:

```
if [ `echo test` == "test"]; then
    echo "echo test outputs test on shell"
fi
```

or

```
if [ $(echo test) == "test"]; then
    echo "echo test outputs test on shell"
fi
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `exit_code` of the previous program like:

```
someprogram
id [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
     someotherprogram
fi
```

*Note*, normally the `0` exit code means successful finish.

You can do it shorter:

```
someprogram && someotherprogram
```

With the above `someotherprogram` only executes if `someprogram` finished successfully. Or if you want to test for unsuccessful exit:

```
someprogram || someotherprogram
```

HTH

Comment: I think he meant the actual output of the command, not its exit code.

Comment: Maybe. Who knows until unspecified?

Comment: I only guessed because I assumed that when one expects the string "test" as the output of the echo command, it's not its exit code.